# Do I need mutex for 1 reader and 1 writer where I don't mind losing some writes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex, ros

I have a ROS node running two threads and they both share the same class. This class has two sets of parameters "to read" and "to write" to be updated in a control loop.
There are two situations where questions arises.

My program is a node that pumps control data into a quadrotor (case 1) and reads the drone data to get feedback (case 2). Here I can control the execution frequency of thread A and I know the frequency at which thread B can communicate with its read/write external source.

1. The thread A reads data from the control source and updates the "to read" parameters. The thread B is constantly reading this "to read" parameters and writting them into the drone source. My point here is that I don't mind if I miss some of the values A thread has read, but thread B could happen to read something that's not a "true" value because thread A is writting or something similar?
2. The thread B after writting the "to read" parameters, reads the state of the drone that will update the second set "to write". Again thread A needs to read this "to write" parameters and write them back to the control source, the same way I don't care if a value is missed because I'll get the next one.

So do I need a mutex here? Or the reading threads will just miss some values but the ones read will be correct and consistent?

BTW: I am using boost:threads to implement the thread B as the thread A it's the ROS node itself.

Comment: Is your data a single value (e.g. a byte) that can be read or written atomically, or is it a larger structure that might get read when it's only been half updated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A data race is undefined behavior. Even if the hardware guarantees atomic access and even your threads never actually access the same data at the same time due to timings. There is no such thing as a benign data race in C++. You can get lucky that the undefined behavior does what you want, but you can never be sure and every new compilation could break everything (not just a missed write). I strongly suggest you use an std::atomic. It will most likely generate almost the same code except that it is guaranteed to always work.

Answer (score 2):

In general the answer is that you need a lock or some other type of synchronization mechanism. For example, if your data is a null-terminated string it's possible for you to read interleaved data. Say one thread was reading the buffer and the string in the buffer is "this is a test". The thread copies the first four bytes and then another thread comes in and overwrites the buffer with "cousin it is crazy". You'd end up copying "thisin it is crazy". That's just one example of things that could go wrong.

If you're always copying atomic types and everything is fixed length, then you *could* get away with it. But if you do, your data is potentially inconsistent. If two values are supposed to be related, it's possible for that relationship now to be broken because you read one value from the previous update and one value from the new update.

Comment: actually, a data race simply invokes undefined behaviour, and as such the whole program is allowed to do anything. At all.